# p:selectOneMenu with converter shows only 1st item as item value while h:selectOneMenu works fine

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this component:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{requestController.backing.selectedRequestVO.requestSituation}" converter="Situation">
     <f:selectItems value="#{requestController.listOrderSituations()}" var="requestSituation" itemLabel="#{requestSituation.description}" itemValue="#{requestSituation}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

It is returning me a list of options that is ok, I have the values and the labels correctly set.

If I change it to `<p:selectOneMenu>` it displays only the first item and only the ID and I can't select the other options.

Other PrimeFaces components are working.

Comment: the last version: `primefaces-3.2`

Comment: Works just fine for me. All I need to do is to change `h:` to `p:`.

Comment: I'm gonna try restarting the server, removing/adding the .jar again to see if anything changes.

Comment: I'd rather put a breakpoint on `getAsString()` of the converter and debug it.

Comment: I don't this is solve because it is working with `h:...`, that is using the same converter but I'm gonna try, thanks.

Comment: It's merely just to check what exactly PrimeFaces is doing and if it's doing it right. It should call the method as many times as the available select items. Also, you can see the call stack in the debugger and navigate into PrimeFaces code from there. This is an easy way to figure what PrimeFaces classes/methods exactly are involved in rendering the `<p:selectOneMenu>`.